# How to properly throw a ValidationError in Django?

Tags: python, django

What's the appropriate way to throw a ValidationError exception in a Django form?

There seems to be a few different mutually-exclusive ways to throw this exception. If I have a custom `clean()` method in a form, and the error doesn't refer to any specific field, then I have to throw it like:

```
raise ValidationError({NON_FIELD_ERRORS: ["Something's wrong!"]})
```

However, if I do this inside a custom `clean()` method of an InlineFormSet, it breaks Django's validation framework and throws the error:

```
AttributeError: 'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'error_list'
```

If I instead change my code to:

```
raise ValidationError("Something's wrong!")
```

then it works just fine and I see a nice user-friendly red validation error on my web page. However, this syntax fails almost anywhere else, and confusingly throws the error `'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'error_list'` if I **don't** use the `raise ValidationError({...})` syntax. Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In any class that inherits from BaseFormSet, `ValidationError`s raised in the `clean` instance method are not associated with any particular form.

By design, you can pass a list to `ValidationError` or a string in `clean` for InlineFormSet. This will ensure that [`self.error_list` is set](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.4/django/core/exceptions.py#L134). This makes sense for formset because it contains a list of forms.

```
raise ValidationError([{NON_FIELD_ERRORS: ["Something's wrong!"]}])
```

This is different for `ValidationError` raised in a `Form` where errors raised are associated with that form. For this reason, forms support passing [`dict`, `str` or `list`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.4/django/forms/forms.py#L338,L346) to ValidationError.

#### References

- [Why you need to pass a list or string to ValidationError in InlineFormSet](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.4/django/forms/formsets.py#L368)
- [InlineFormSet errors are not associated with any form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.4/django/forms/formsets.py#L372,L375)